# Correct method to save and restore leaftlet drawing into mysql database

Tags: polygon, leaflet, layers, mysql, leaflet-draw

I have the following code for saving my coordinates of what I draw. So what I do on drawing created I have the following function.

```
 map.on(L.Draw.Event.CREATED, function (e) {

        var type = e.layerType,
                layer = e.layer;
        var points = JSON.stringify(e.layer.toGeoJSON());

        console.log("coord : "+e.layer.toGeoJSON().geometry.coordinates);
        var latlngs = [];
          latlngs = LatLngsToCoords(e.layer._latlngs, 1);

        if (type === 'marker') {
            layer.bindPopup('A popup!');
        }
        if (type === 'polygon'){

        console.log("coord : "+e.layer.toGeoJSON().geometry.coordinates);


        }

        drawnItems.addLayer(layer);
    });
```

This output `e.layer.toGeoJSON().geometry.coordinates` gives me example so I will then transfer it into `175.28162956237796,-37.77007019461929,175.28506278991702,-37.77271618103962,175.27849674224854,-37.77458188377217,175.27781009674072,-37.77376776473304,175.28162956237796,-37.77007019461929`

into `POLYGON(( 175.28162956237796 -37.77007019461929,175.28506278991702 -37.77271618103962,175.27849674224854 -37.77458188377217,175.27781009674072 -37.77376776473304,175.28162956237796 -37.77007019461929 ))`

I know I could do this and save into the MySQL database.

For the reverse when I need to restore the polygon I will need to extract the POLYGON and now reverse the latitude and longitude back.

I find there is a lot of steps. Is there any direct method ?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend looking into this approach:

[`L.GeoJson`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#geojson) layer and pointing Leaflet.draw at it.

You can iterate over drawn objects with `drawnItems.eachLayer()` method and add any objects to the layer.

Comment: actually at one time I only need one object to be present and user need to deal with only one to avoid confusion. Because after drawing I am going to pop-up for them to enter details before they save into database